# Import variable for class ato another class

Tags: java, class, variables, import

I want to transfer a variable from a class `FenJeu` to another class `FenInfos`. The variable `butrouge` and `butbleu` should go from `FenJeu` to a class called `FenInfos`.

`FenJeu` **class** :

```
public class Joueurs extends JLabel {
        public int butrouge = 0;
        public int butbleu = 0;

            if(xba < 130 && yba > 447 && yba < 607) {
                butbleu = butbleu + 1;
            }
            if(xba > 1564 && yba > 447 && yba < 607) {
                butrouge = butrouge + 1;
             }
```

Should I put the variables in a public field ?

Comment: "..transfer...?" If you mean to access them -> use getter/setter

Comment: you mean you want to get their values? just use getters. Just saying, the code you posted will never compile. code like that (conditional statements and such) must be inside either a block, a constructor or a method

Comment: Actually, the real code is not this one i really shorten it to be as understable as possible. 
By transfer I mean, I want to get their value from antoher class. I set their values in a class and I want to check them in antoher class.

Comment: Just create a getter for the variables butrouge and butbleu in FenJeu then call it on FenInfos. Getter basically just is just a method that return the value of a variable something like: `public int getButrouge() { return butrouge; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding of your question, you want to access your variables from another class.

You can try importing your class and then using getter functions you can fetch those variables into any classes you want.
Either use inheritance or import that class and call a function from that class which will fetch that value and save it into this immediate class.

[Reference Link for Importing](https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/java/package-and-import-20.html)

PS - FenJeu class - The code that you put up there wont work unless you put those condition inside a function.

Comment: I did this in teh first class :

`public int getButrouge() { 
   return butrouge; }
  public void setButrouge(int newButrouge) {
   this.butrouge = newButrouge;
  }`

In the second class should i write something like this  ? :

`but obj = new but();
  obj.setButrouge(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume this is your first class and other class also is in the same package

```
package testDataTrial;

public class TestDate { 

public int test = 0;

public void dummyMethod() {
    // method content
}
```

In the second class, you can create an object for the class. of which you ant to access the variables. and then acess the variable by doing Object.Variable / Method

```
package testDataTrial;

public class TestTwo {


public static TestDate td = new TestDate();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    td.test = 1;
    td.dummyMethod();
 }
}
```